# ReactJS with vscode dev containers - hot reload issue

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using vscode's Remote-Containers to do React development.  My dev dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM node
```

I then open the directory containing the dev dockerfile with remote-containers and create an example React project with:

```
npx create-react-app testapp
cd testapp
npm start
```

Everything works fine and I can access the test application via the browser on my local machine via http://localhost:3000.  The issue is that when I modify any of the code, the changes are not reflected in the browser (even if I refresh the browser).  I have to restart the dev server for my changes to take effect.

I have tried setting `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` but that had no effect.